# Static class property pointing to special instance of the same class in Python

Tags: python, class

Coming from cpp/c#, how does one refer to the same class in the class body in Python:

```
class Foo(object):
    ANSWER = Foo(42)
    FAIL = Foo(-1)

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._v = value
```

When I try to use this code, I get "name 'Foo' is not defined" exception in a line trying to instantiate the ANSWER instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `Foo` is not set until the full class body has been executed. The only way you can do what you want is to add attributes to the class *after* the `class` statement has completed:

```
class Foo(object):    
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._v = value

Foo.ANSWER = Foo(42)
Foo.FAIL = Foo(-1)
```

It sounds like you are re-inventing Python's [`enum` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html); it lets you define a class with constants that are really instances of that class:

```
 from enum import Enum

 class Foo(Enum):
     ANSWER = 42
     FAIL = -1
```

After that `class` statement has run, `Foo.ANSWER` is an instance of `Foo` with a `.value` attribute set to `42`.